# Food for thought!

Tags: phrase-request

*Food for thought* is very common English expression meaning:

> - An idea or issue to ponder, as in 'That interesting suggestion of yours has given us food for thought.'  (It is a  metaphoric phrase that uses  the idea of digestion to indicate something  in the mind.)

- *Cibo per la mente* is generally used as a translation. What other expressions can best convey the meaning of  'food for thought'?

Comment: _spunti interessanti_?

Answer (score 8):

According to wordreference, you can also translate it with ["spunto di riflessione" or "stimolo per una riflessione"](http://www.wordreference.com/enit/food+for+thought).

Answer (score 4):

Possible equivalent sentences:
"Il suo interessante suggerimento/intervento  ci ha dato molto su cui pensare/ riflettere" (= Your interesting suggestion gave us a lot to think about).
"Il suo spunto ci ha dato molto su cui riflettere".

An expression with related meaning:
Digerire qualcosa (to digest something).
Example: "Quanto mi dici non è facile da digerire!" (= What you're telling me is not easy to accept/ absorb).

Anyway, "cibo per la mente" is definitely not used as an idiom like "food for thought" is in English.